# Any difference between 'b' and 'c'?

Tags: python, class

```
class a(object):
    b = 'bbbb'
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 'cccc'
```

I think they are the same; is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> class a(object):
...     b = 'bbbb'
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.c = 'cccc'
...
>>> a1=a()
>>> a2=a()
>>> a1.b
'bbbb'
>>> a2.b
'bbbb'
>>> a1.c='dddd'
>>> a1.c
'dddd'
>>> a2.c
'cccc'
>>> a.b= 'common'
>>> a1.b
'common'
>>> a2.b
'common'
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a difference.

`b` is a class variable... one that is shared by all instances of `a`, while `c` is an instance variable which will exist independantly for each instance.

Comment: You probably mean "yes", since there *is* a difference.

Answer (score 5):

`b` is a class variable, while `c` is a instance variable.

```
>>> a.b
'bbbb'
>>> a.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'a' has no attribute 'c'
>>> a().b
'bbbb'
>>> a().c
'cccc'
```

Instances of the class may have different value for their instance variables, but they share the same class variables.

Answer (score 2):

'b' is a class attribute, set directly on the class object 'a'.  'c' is an instance attribute, set directly on self.  While `self.b` will find `a.b` due to how lookup works, you cannot use `a.c` (as it doesn't exist).